# How to read the chart below in jmeter

Tags: graph, jmeter, throughput

In the graph, the throughput is equal to 116.264 minutes. What does this mean?

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per docs:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Graph_Results

> Throughput - plot the number of samples per unit of time